# ¿Cómo muestro en pantalla solamente el nombre del usuario logeado?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

¡Hola buenas! tengo este código en mi documetno HTML, el código debería mostrar en pantalla únicamente el nombre del usuario logeado, pero muestra en pantalla todos los nombres que están registrados en la base de datos. Necesito su ayuda para solucionar este problema, se los agradeceria un montón.

PD:
En el archivo de inicio de sesión únicamente solicita el correo y contraseña con que se registraron. No pide el nombre de usuario que introdujo anteriormente en el registro.

```html
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $consulta);
while($row = $resultado->fetch_array()){
 $nombre = $row['usuario'];
}



include("close-conexion.php");
?>

<h2><?php echo $nombre; ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando el usuario inicia sesion debes buscar el correo en la base de datos

```
$q="select usuario from usuarios where email=".$email
```

Y eso deberia hacer que solo te regrese un usuario

Comment: Osea el sistema de logeo funciona con Correo y Contraseña, lo que quiero es que al momento de entrar muestre el usuario con el que se registraron previamente

Comment: Es exactamente lo que te indique, lo que tu haces es un select de todos los usuarios de la base de datos, y lo que ocupas es hacer un select únicamente del usuario que ya inició sesión

Comment: Sería mucho pedir que me escribas exactamente lo que debo poner en el documento. Soy nuevo en PHP y qusiera que me brindaras un poco de tu ayuda por favor, de antemano te lo agradecería.